# Next.js - link back to start page and restore previous scroll position on that page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

For my next.js app, I'm trying create a "back to start"-link, that behaves like this:

1. User starts at start page and scrolls down.
2. User navigates to a subpage and finds the "back to start"-link there.
3. User click on "back to start", is redirected to the start page, BUT the scroll position on the start page is the same as when it was left.

On the other hand, if the user enters the subpage directly, via url, then the "back to start" button should simply lead to the start page scrolled to top.

I've setup a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reverent-tree-v85t6s?file=/app/page.tsx:15,1) for this.

What I've tried so far:

- Use next.js `<Link>`component. But this will redirect to the start page scrolled to top
- Use the `scroll={false}` property for next.js `<Link>`. But this just keeps the current scroll position, it doesn't restore the scroll position that we had when we left the start page.
- Use next.js `router.back()`. This actually does the trick, but it doesn't work if the user navigated the subpage directly via url.

Do you have any suggestions? Maybe a combination of the above strategies?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [next-scroll-restorer](https://github.com/RevoTale/next-scroll-restorer) if you are using an [app directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/app).

It's the ideal solution for scroll restoration in Next.js.